# Download file using FTP and PHP

Tags: php, ftp

I would like to start a upload and download website for huge files (up to 1gb). I thought that it would be better to download the files using FTP (with PHP), because this protocol is especially used for these types of transfers.

The cliënt gets an email, including a download link to download the file (like yousendit.com). When they click on the link a download box appears. My problem is that I don't know how to show a download box using ftp and php. I have read that it isn't possible to immediately download a file by PHP, using FTP. Is this correct? 
Do I have to create a temporary files on the server to let the client download the file? If yes, is this also a good solution for huge files?

What do you advice me to give the clients the possibility to download these huge files?

Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Would you be willing to listen to the idea of you manually uploading a large file to the server then the user clicks a link to download. This isn't FTP - rather force download.

Comment: Yes, users can be upload a file and other users can download this file using a unique link. What is the limit of the file size when using a force download? And is it stable enough for downloading huge files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate unique address based on session_id (create this folder on runtime and move huge file there) and redirect user to this link
For example, you have file huge.tgz

```
1. Send you client link http://***/user/john/file/huge.tgz
2. Ask user for auth in this page if they lost session
3. get session id
4. create on your server folder with name equals session id and move huge.tgz here
5. redirect user to unique ftp link ftp://***/17oe5kf8iYmpt66bjs89hcuo83/huge.tgz
```

You should disallow list files and directories on ftp server

Comment: hmm, how long does it take to move a file to a unique location? And how can you redirect the user to a ftp location? By header('Location: ftp://.....'); ? And the user has the possibility to download the file more than once.

Comment: if the file is on the same server and partition - less then a second. And yes with php header function or javascript location.href

Comment: If you don't want to move file. You can copy it. It takes some minutes. By ajax request server if file is ready (size of file in unique dir equals size on original file) and than redirect by javascript

Comment: The only thing I have to do is deleting files when they are downloaded or isn't downloaded anyway. Hmm, the files has to be ready when the user opens the link, so copying a file isn't the solution I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you send them an FTP link ? Why do you need PHP?

ftp://ftp12.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ls-lR.gz

Comment: The files need to be protected, so clients can't download files from others. With a direct ftp link it is also possible to download other files on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use PHP to handle everything but the file transfer. Once you have done all the checks you want you can redirect the browser to the file specifying the protocol as ftp. though you won't be able to have a progression bar in your site, the browser/ftp app will probably display one.

Comment: But in your case users can be download other files on the server when they know the filename, right? Is it better to connect to the ftp server using php?